# Print field from first record in a group in the group footer

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a series of transactions that contain a receive and return date and are grouped.  In the group footer, I want to print the receive date of the first record in the group and the return date of the last record in the group.  I created a formula to populate only when it is the first record in the group. But if the group contains more than one record, the formula field prints out blank.  If there is only one record in the group, it prints OK. I'm using SAP Business Object Crystal Reports 2013.

Comment: Is the group sorted based on date? For example, is the first date the earliest in time?

Comment: The group is based on project number, not dates.  I could probably use MIN since the dates will most likely be in sequence. but this is the way it was setup when I took it over and I'm trying to make it work.  And also trying to avoid any problems if/when the dates are not in sequence for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this. If you were sorting by Date, (which I've just learned you aren't) you could use a Summary to find the Minimum value. You'd place it in the relevant Group Footer and it should reset each time.

But since you're *not* sorting them by Date, I'd try setting up a Running Total that counts the number of records in the current Group (and resets on change of group.) Then set up a Shared Variable in a Formula that gets set every time the Group Count resets to 1. Finally, put *another* Formula in the Group Footer which prints out the Shared Variable.

Done correctly each Group Footer will display the first date value in that Group.

Comment: I'm pretty much doing that now.  There is a sequence # that starts with 1 and increments and resets for each group.  I setup a formula field to hold the value of the field when the sequence # = 1. But when I print it after multiple records in the group, the field is blank.  I'm just using a regular formula field. Should I be using something else?

Comment: Interesting. Can you include edit your original question to include those formulas? That would make it easier to diagnose where it's going wrong.